# How to add an object to the value of another object

Tags: powershell, object

I have a script that captures the state of a systems services and volumes. It captures a snapshot of the services and saves them locally to a JSON file, on the next run it gets all service statuses, loads the JSON and compares the two objects for differences. These differences are then saved to an object and sent to an API.

All I am trying to do (and failing dramatically at) is add `$Changes` to `$Data.state_changes.$Target` so that Service changes are added to `$Data.state_changes.services` and Volume changes are added to `$Data.state_changes.volumes`.

An example of `$Changes` is:

```
Name                    : AppXSvc
Status                  : OK
ExitCode                : 0
ErrorControl            : Normal
PathName                : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k wsappx -p
StartMode               : Manual
DelayedAutoStart        : False
DisplayName             : AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC)
InstallDate             : 
ServiceSpecificExitCode : 0
Started                 : True
StartName               : LocalSystem
State                   : Running
SideIndicator           : previous_state

Name                    : AppXSvc
Status                  : OK
ExitCode                : 0
ErrorControl            : Normal
PathName                : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k wsappx -p
StartMode               : Manual
DelayedAutoStart        : False
DisplayName             : AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC)
InstallDate             : 
ServiceSpecificExitCode : 0
Started                 : False
StartName               : LocalSystem
State                   : Stopped
SideIndicator           : current_state
```

So all I'm trying to figure out is, what's the best way of adding an object (all similar to `$changes` show above) to a PSObject? I'm sure it's not hard but I have no idea why I cannot get this to work.

I originally thought it would be as simple as:

`Add-Member -InputObject $Data."state_changes" -NotePropertyName $Target -NotePropertyValue $Changes`

```
# Called using `Get-SystemState services,volumes`
# Requires the folder %ProgramData%\VACS\states`

function Get-SystemState {

    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,ParameterSetName='Targets')]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]
        $Targets
    )

    begin {
        $Data = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $Data -NotePropertyName "state_changes" -NotePropertyValue ([PSCustomObject]@{}) -force
        $FilePath = "$Env:PROGRAMDATA\VACS\states\"
    }

    process {
        foreach($Target in $Targets){
            switch ($Target) {
                services {
                    $State = gwmi win32_service | Select-Object Name, Status, ExitCode, ErrorControl, PathName, StartMode, 
                                    Caption, DelayedAutoStart, Description, DisplayName, InstallDate, ServiceSpecificExitCode, 
                                    Started, StartName, State
                    $Snapshot = Get-Content -Raw -Path (Join-Path "$FilePath" "$Target.json") | ConvertFrom-Json
                    $Changes = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($Snapshot) -DifferenceObject ($State) `
                                        -Property Name, Status, ExitCode, ErrorControl, PathName, StartMode,DelayedAutoStart, 
                                        DisplayName, InstallDate, ServiceSpecificExitCode, Started, StartName, State |
                                        ForEach-Object {
                                            $_.SideIndicator = $_.SideIndicator -replace "=>","previous_state" -replace "<=","current_state"
                                            $_
                                        })
                }
                volumes {
                    $State = Get-Volume | Select-Object OperationalStatus,HealthStatus,DriveType,FileSystemType, DedupMode,UniqueId,
                                AllocationUnitSize,FileSystemLabel,FileSystem,Size,
                                @{n='DriveLetter';e={if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.DriveLetter)){""}else{$_.DriveLetter}}}

                    $Snapshot = Get-Content -Raw -Path (Join-Path "$FilePath" "$Target.json") | ConvertFrom-Json
                    $Changes = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($Snapshot) -DifferenceObject ($State) `
                                    -Property OperationalStatus,HealthStatus,DriveType,FileSystemType,DedupMode,UniqueId,AllocationUnitSize,
                                    FileSystemLabel,FileSystem,Size,DriveLetter |
                                    ForEach-Object {
                                        $_.SideIndicator = $_.SideIndicator -replace '=>','previous_state' -replace '<=','current_state'
                                        $_
                                    })
                }
            }

            if($Changes.Count -gt 0){

                Add-Member -InputObject $Data."state_changes" -NotePropertyName $Target -NotePropertyValue ([PSCustomObject]@{}) -force
                Add-Member -InputObject $Data."state_changes".$Target -NotePropertyName "timestamp" -NotePropertyValue "$((Get-Date).ToString())" -force

                write-host $Changes.Count "changes detected in $Target"

                For($i=0; $i -lt $Changes.Count; $i++){
                    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -InputObject $Data."state_changes".$Target -NotePropertyName $i -NotePropertyValue $Change -force
                }


            }
            $State | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path (Join-Path "$FilePath" "$Target.json") -Force
        }
    }

    end {
        Send-Payload $Data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these kind of tasks I would really recommend you to use `hashtable` as buffer object. You can populate it with properties(add/update/remove) when this its needed. As well as make it nested object. Once its complete you can make `PSObject` using hastable as property list and then convert it to JSON.

Like so:

```
$HashTable = @{}
$HashTable['state_changes'] = @{}
$HashTable['state_changes']['One'] = 1
$HashTable['state_changes']['Two'] = 2
if ($MyServiceState -eq 'Ready'){$HashTable.Add('MyServiceState','Ready')}
if ($MySrvSize -gt 90){$HashTable.Add('FreeSpaceCheck','Warning')}
if ($UpTime -lt 10){$HashTable.Add('UpTimeCheck',$UpTime)}
$HashTable['FreeSpaceCheck'] = 'OK'
$PSObject = New-Object PSObject -Property $HashTable
```

I hope you get the point!

Also, there is seem to be a typo in your code over here:

```
Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -InputObject $Data."state_changes".$Target -NotePropertyName $i -NotePropertyValue $Change -force
```

You trying to call for **$Change** instead of **$Changes**.

Comment: Sorry, the `$Change` was there as the For loop used to be a Foreach (For each change in changes). In your example we can see `$key=>$Value` which is nice and straight-forward. Is the behaviour the same if $value is an array?

Comment: Actually, your answers perfect and I've been looking at handling my data all wrong since I started learning. I've got it all sorted, thanks!

Comment: @Arbiter, glad I could help!